# Autofac fails to initailly resolve object from remote assembly (cast to know type)

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, autofac, remoting

Here is my WCF(vs2015@net452) autofac (v4.6.1) setup:

`MyService.dll:`

```
builder.Register(c => (ISession)RemoteObjectFactory.GetInstance(typeof(MySessionBase))).As<ISession>().SingleInstance();
...
var session = AutofacHostFactory.Container.Resolve<ISession>();

<Message>An exception was thrown while executing a resolve operation. See the InnerException for details.
Could not load file or assembly "MyRemotingHost, Version=1.0.6442.29085, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" or one of its dependencies. File not found(See inner exception for details.)</Message>
<StackTrace>at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)&#xD;
at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object&amp; instance)&#xD;
at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)&#xD;
at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)&#xD;
at My.DoSomeWork() at C:\Projects\...
<Type>Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException</Type>
```

`MyService.dll` refers to `MyDefs.dll`.

`MyRemotingHost.dll` refers to `MyDefs.dll`.

`MyService.dll` calls `MyRemotingHost.dll` via remoting. `RemoteObjectFactory.GetInstance` is a wrapper method that returns(via remoting) Transparent Proxy to `MySession` object from `MyRemotingHost.dll`.

Abstract class `MySessionBase` implements `ISession`. Both are defined in `MyDefs.dll`.

Class `MySession` is a sublcass of `MySessionBase` and is defined in `MyRemotingHost.dll`.

Strictly speaking `MyService.dll` does not know about `MyRemotingHost.dll` and should not know about it. Why then autofac tries to get information about this assembly which is remote??

**Update**

```
ISession session = (MySessionBase)RemoteObjectFactory.GetInstance(typeof(MySessionBase));
builder.RegisterInstance(session);
```

RegisterInstance throws same error.

**Update2**
Second(and subsequent) resolution attempts *do not throw* error which is weird.

```
builder.Register(c => (ISession)RemoteObjectFactory.GetInstance(typeof(MySessionBase))).As<ISession>().SingleInstance();
...
var session1 = AutofacHostFactory.Container.Resolve<ISession>();
var session2 = AutofacHostFactory.Container.Resolve<ISession>();
```

Line `var session1 = ...` throws error. If error is suppressed, then next  line `var session2 = ...` DOES NOT produce error.

PDB-based step-by-step debugging shows that error source is at `Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation` inside `foreach` loop at the 1st call to enumerator:

```
private void CompleteActivations()
{
    var completed = _successfulActivations;
    ResetSuccessfulActivations();

    foreach (var activation in completed)
        activation.Complete();
}
```

I cannot investigate more as I am stuck to VS2015 while autofac sources have VS2017 format already.

Comment: This sounds like it's a 100% remoting problem, nothing at all to do with Autofac, especially since the error pops up even when you take Autofac out of the picture. You might consider updating the question title to something more remoting-oriented to get the right set(s) of eyes on this.

Comment: Error does NOT pop without autofac. `Session` is transparent proxy. That seems to be the problem.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding. If you _don't_ call `RegisterInstance` then the object `session` is fine? It's unclear if the call to `RemoteObjectFactory.GetInstance` is the thing causing the problem or if the resolution via Autofac is. From the "Update" it sounds like it's the call to `RemoteObjectFactory.GetInstance`, which would mean a more remoting-related title could get you a more appropriate set of help.

Comment: I have edited Update to make it clear. Without autofac it works fine.

Comment: @TravisIllig Update2 - error is still there, but it happens only once which is strange.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm rusty on remoting and it's not really a common use case nowadays, so there's not much I can do. Likely it had something to do with the object living in the remote domain and being proxied/marshaled but you really need some remoting expertise on this, which isn't me.

Comment: @TravisIllig It was log4net module which caused troubles. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the [log4net autofac module](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/examples/log4net.html):

```
var instanceType = instance.GetType();
```

Adding checks before that line solves the problem:

```
// cant use GetType() on TransparentProxy as it may throw error
if (RemotingServices.IsTransparentProxy(instance)) return;
```